# Get image from server and preview it on client

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

So i'm trying to get an image from a server and previewing it on the client, i can retrieve the image for now, but i don't know how to preview it on a web page asynchronously.

```
axios.get(link,{responseType:'stream'}).then(img=>{
// What i have to do here ?
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think it would be much easier to simply set a `src` value to an `<img>` in react. Something like `<img src={link} />` should be good enough. The browser will load the image for you if you do that.

Comment: thank you but it's not what i need

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood you. What exactly are you trying to do? It sounded like you were trying to load an image over ajax and then display it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to fetch your image with the response type `arraybuffer`. Then you can convert the result to a base64 string and assign it as `src` of an image tag. Here is a small example with React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Image extends Component {
  state = { source: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        'https://www.example.com/image.png',
        { responseType: 'arraybuffer' },
      )
      .then(response => {
        const base64 = btoa(
          new Uint8Array(response.data).reduce(
            (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
            '',
          ),
        );
        this.setState({ source: "data:;base64," + base64 });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <img src={this.state.source} />;
  }
}

export default Image;
```